# How to convert a dynamic JSON like file to a CSV file

Tags: json, csv, parsing, data-conversion, format-conversion

I have a file which looks exactly as below.

```
{"eventid" : "12345" ,"name":"test1","age":"18"}
{"eventid" : "12346" ,"age":"65"}
{"eventid" : "12336" ,"name":"test3","age":"22","gender":"Male"}
```

Think of the above file as event.json

The number of data objects may vary per line.
I would like the following csv output. and it would be output.csv

```
eventid,name,age,gender
12345,test1,18
12346,,65
12336,test3,22,Male
```

Could someone kindly help me? I could accept the answer from an any scripting language (Javascript, Python and etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will collect all the headers dynamically and write the file to CSV.

Read comments in code for details:

```
import json

# Load data from file
data = '''{"eventid" : "12345" ,"name":"test1","age":"18"}
{"eventid" : "12346" ,"age":"65"}
{"eventid" : "12336" ,"name":"test3","age":"22","gender":"Male"}'''

# Store records for later use
records = [];

# Keep track of headers in a set
headers = set([]);

for line in data.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip();

    # Parse each line as JSON
    parsedJson = json.loads(line)

    records.append(parsedJson)

    # Make sure all found headers are kept in the headers set
    for header in parsedJson.keys():
        headers.add(header)

# You only know what headers were there once you have read all the JSON once.

#Now we have all the information we need, like what all possible headers are.

outfile = open('output_json_to_csv.csv','w')

# write headers to the file in order
outfile.write(",".join(sorted(headers)) + '\n')

for record in records:
    # write each record based on available fields
    curLine = []
    # For each header in alphabetical order
    for header in sorted(headers):
        # If that record has the field
        if record.has_key(header):
            # Then write that value to the line
            curLine.append(record[header])
        else:
            # Otherwise put an empty value as a placeholder
            curLine.append('')
    # Write the line to file
    outfile.write(",".join(curLine) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

Comment: I'd probably go with this solution, now that you've added the handling of unknown headers to it. It would have been nice to know of that detail in advance.

Comment: {"eventid" : "12345" ,"name":"test1","age":18}
{"eventid" : "12346" ,"age":65}
{"eventid" : "12336" ,"name":"test3","age":22,"gender":"Male"}  - If I pass age has integers it doesn't work and throws an error.

Comment: @mmenschig Error says outfile.write(",".join(curLine) + '\n') TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found. You should be able to determine why its failing from this message. Please try, what do you think this error means?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If `filter.jq` contains the following filter

```
  (reduce (.[]|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ({};.[$k]="")) as $o   # object with all keys
| ($o  | keys_unsorted), (.[] | $o * . | [.[]])              # generate header and data
| join(",")                                                  # convert to csv
```

and `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
$ jq -Mrs -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
eventid,name,age,gender
12345,test1,18,
12346,,65,
12336,test3,22,Male
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution (should work in both Python 2 & 3).
I'm not proud of the code, as there's probably a better way to do this (using the csv module) but this gives you the desired output.

I've taken the liberty of naming your JSON data `data.json` and I'm naming the output csv file `output.csv`.

```
import json

header = ['eventid', 'name', 'age', 'gender']

with open('data.json', 'r') as infile, \
     open('outfile.csv', 'w+') as outfile:

    # Writes header row
    outfile.write(','.join(header))
    outfile.write('\n')

    for row in infile:
        line = ['', '', '', ''] # I'm sure there's a better way
        datarow = json.loads(row)

        for key in datarow:
            line[header.index(key)] = datarow[key]

        outfile.write(','.join(line))
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is great with one big problem (Which I wasn't probably clear about). How about if I don't know of the possible headers? let's say my next line of the data.json file has "address" now. Is there a way to tackle that ?

Comment: Ha, that changes the entire nature of this exercise. So you're saying you don't know what the actual header row is and if it's a new entry to append it to the end?

Answer (score 0):

Using Angularjs with ngCsv plugin we can generate csv file from desired json with dynamic headers.

[Run in plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/n1nNd6wMkdzylgYAclaY?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

 var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngSanitize", "ngCsv"]);

 myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.filename = "test";
   $scope.getArray = [{
     label: 'Apple',
     value: 2,
     x:1,
   }, {
     label: 'Pear',
     value: 4,
     x:38
   }, {
     label: 'Watermelon',
     value: 4,
     x:38
   }];


   $scope.getHeader = function() {
    var vals = [];
    for( var key in $scope.getArray ) {
    for(var k in $scope.getArray[key]){
      vals.push(k);
     }
     break;
    }
    return vals;
    
   };

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
   
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-csv/0.3.6/ng-csv.min.js"></script>
   

  </head>


  <body>

    <div ng-app="myapp">

      <div class="container" ng-controller="myctrl">

        <div class="page-header">

          <h1>ngCsv <small>example</small></h1>

        </div>
       
        

        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-csv="getArray" csv-header="getHeader()" filename="{{ filename }}.csv" field-separator="," decimal-separator=".">Export to CSV with header</button>

       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function(el) { return el });
var content = "";
for(var element in arr){
    content += element + ",";
}

var filePath = "someFile.csv";
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 8, false, 0);
fh.WriteLine(content);
fh.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you meant about. I want to dynamically capture the column headers.

Comment: initial file would be something like events.json and the output will be in output.csv. Do you follow ? Where would I pass the location of the event.json file on this script ?